# The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csproj

I'm getting the following error while trying to load some projects in visual studio 2012:

```
G:\path\project.csproj : error  : The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length.
```

I'm trying this with a fresh start on the machine after a svn checkout. These projects can be loaded on other machines correctly.

Can some one help me out with this one? Google didn't give me the answer, I hope SO will.

**EDIT**

This is the relevant part of the csproj file.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(StyleCopTargets)" />

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you paste in the content of the file project.csproj, or at least the relevant part.

Comment: Temporary remove the line with StyleCopTargets and try again, does that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write you start from fresh. I suspect StyleCop isn't installed so the alias value is replaced with a blank leaving the field also blank.

Either remove the reference or install StyleCop. I think that should do the trick.

edit: just for convenience:
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well I installed stylecop and this error still is happening

Comment: Adding stylecop github link: https://github.com/StyleCop , because the codeplex is going down