# Value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid in VS2012, but works good in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I got the following error when trying to load a project using VS2012.

```
error  : The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length.
```

I checked the code and think this might be where the error comes, since VS2012 is not recognizing the "EnvironmentConfig" variable:

```
<Import Project="$(EnvironmentConfig)" />
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732224/the-value-of-the-project-attribute-in-element-import-is-invalid-vs2012) answer which said to install or remove StyleCop, but it didn't work for me.

Actually me and one of my colleague are checking out the same source code, and he is using VS2013 without any other softs like ReSharper or StyleCop, and he can run the exactly same project correctly.

Any advice?
And also how can I check the value of $(EnvironmentConfig)? I don't know where it is defined.

Comment: Just started trying to hunt down this issue and found your question, any tips of what solved it?

Comment: @MattSanders my VS is lacking of some env var definition, I found a way to get these back with a internal tool. VS2013 may have its own way...

Comment: Same issue I am facing in VS 2019

Comment: This issue happens because the env var is not set. Maybe try opening from cmd with `devenv Folder\File.sln`. It will allow VS to inherit the vars set in your enlistment.